# Pressing Enter fire change event in google chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have code run when pressing enter key but when  pressing enter inside textbox 
fire textchanged  event only on google chrome but working well in firefox .
I donot want to fire textchanged event when pressing enter only with tab key.

this my  enter code

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#<%=Save.ClientID %>").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and much easier way us to wrap the TextBoxes and the Save button with a Panel and assign a `DefaultButton` to the Panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Now when you press enter in either TextBox, it will simulate the clicking of `Button1`.
This only works with `Button`, not `LinkButton`.